# Are all Contraction Mappings Differentiable?

Tags: analysis

I've managed to prove that all contraction mappings are continuous by using the definition of continuity and picking a $\delta = \varepsilon/c$ where $c$ is the constant in the definition of a contraction mapping.

I can set up a limit that resembles the definition of differentiability livert mit as $\lVert h\rVert$ approaches zero of $\dfrac{\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert - c\lVert h\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}$ is $\le 0$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 7):

No, $x\rightarrow {{\mid x\mid} \over 2}$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow [-1,1]$ defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{2} & x \in [-1, 0]\\
\frac{x}{3} & x \in [0, 1]\\
\end{cases}$$

It is clearly a contraction, but not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Apologies for bringing up an old thread, but isn't $f$ discontinuous $\implies$ $f$ is not a contraction? Also as $f$ is currently defined it is ambiguous what happens when $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Student Oh, indeed! Thank you, I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a "because-it-has-a-different-name" reason why the answer is "no".

A contraction mapping is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity). Viceversa, given a Lipschitz continuous map $f$, there exists a constant $0<\alpha<1$ such that $\alpha f$ is a contraction.

Since multiplying by a non-zero constant does not change the differentiability of a function, you are basically asking if every Lipschitz continuous map is differentiable. Which is false.

Typically, though, this last statement is proved by showing a counterexample such as the ones in Tsemo Aristide's and lisyarus' answers.